# Protecting smart devices on my local network

Tags: network, network-scanners, network-access-control, iot

I have a network of smart devices I have created, I wish to make more secure from attackers.

I have implemented a Gateway on a Data Stream Network (DSN) to allow users to access these devices and wish to secure the devices themselves so they cannot get around the gateway, e.g., Accessing the devices directly/their controllers.

**Aim:**

- Hide these devices on a single IP address

  - At least long enough to detect any attacks for example.

**Current ideas**

- Cloak the devices in the sense fakes of these devices are raised to confuse attackers.
- Hide the device perhaps on a subnet?

---

1. How would I go about doing this?

   - Does not *have* to be cloaking, just prevent them from being accessed directly.
2. What tools would I need (hardware/software)?